# how to move video file by laravel

Tags: php, laravel, video, laravel-4, move

I tried to move mp4 video from directory to another by File::move ... but the source video and moved video stop working after moving.

PHP:

```
$from="assets/vids/".$filename."";
try{
    mkdir("assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id."");
} catch(Exception $e){}
$to="assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id."/".$filename."";
try{
    File::move($from,$to);
} catch(Exception $e){}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('end-video') }}" method="post" id="end-live-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" files>
    <input type="hidden" id="input-timer" name="timer">
    <a type="submit" id="end-btn">إنهاء البث</a>
    <div id="end-sure">
        <p>هل انت متأكد من انهاء البث</p>
        <button type="submit" id="end-live-btn">نعم</button>
        <a class="no">لا</a>
    </div>
    {{ Form::token() }}
</form>
```

Comment: What is the relation between the PHP code, and the blade file? Also, what do you mean by not working? What is the exact error?

Comment: video move correctly but when played with video player not working

Comment: Are you sure, it is working before moving? Also is that an uploaded file? Are you sure the file is uploaded correctly?

Comment: yes 
before move file worked correctly but after moving video not working

Comment: how do you test it? are you using Javascript/Flash player? Are you sure the file is accessible after moving it?

Comment: i test it on my pc at localhost with windows video player

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PHP: rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function. I think it is easier. This shouldn't damage the file.

Or change mkdir to `mkdir("assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id, 0755);`.

**- EDIT -**

Try this:

```
$from = "assets/vids/".$filename;
$to = "assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id."/".$filename;
try {
    mkdir("assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id, 0755);
    File::move($from, $to);
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',$e->getMessage(),"\n";
}
```

Let's see what the exception is.

**- END EDIT -**

Comment: case the same problem

Comment: Try adding the mode parameter, set the directory to 0755 on `mkdir()`.

Comment: @user3718167 that's odd, did you try outputting the `exception` to see if anything happens? I know it shouldn't but, seems like a huge bug on the system if not, that it does.

Comment: the error in file size ... it moved with size less than real size

Comment: @user3718167 in that case, try copying the file instead of moving it, just for the sake of knowing if it's the function not working properly. If it works that way, then we can be sure we found the problem. Of course, we then solve it.

Comment: copy or move cause same problem :(

Comment: @user3718167 don't give up. Did you test this on the server or just your computer? If the file actually did move, it's not a path problem, it must be a read/write problem. I suggest you try `is_readable();` PHP function to see if you can actually read the file. If it doesn't, then it won't move and that will be the problem.

Comment: i tried to move file with real existed name such as "file.mp4" ... move correctly without any problem
but when i use my variables in file name such as "assets/vids/USER".Auth::user()->id."/".$filename."" cause this problem

Comment: @user3718167 By the way... there is no need to add `.""` at the end of each variable or parameter because it won't concatenate anything at all...